# Display a UITableView in a Split View Controller using code

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I have Two different `UITableView` with two `Navigation Controller`.
I want to display one of them after touching a `UIButton` in first Table.
In iPhone I use following code

```
SecondNavigationController second = [SecondNavigationController new];
[self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
```

Note that first is first `TableViewController`; And second `navigation controller` it self initiate a `UITableView` and display it using following code in it's `ViewDidLoad` method.

```
SecondTableViewController *root = [SecondTableViewController new];
[self pushViewController:root animated:NO];
```

Note that first `TableView` uses application root view controller in iPhone to display it!
And it perfectly works.

In iPad, on the other hand, I use a `splitViewController` which shows first table view on the left side screen.

I want to show second `TableView` in the left side too. But above code is not working perfectly. It covers all of iPad screen.

How can I show second `UITableView`

Answer (score 0):

You need a conditional check which does (pseudo code):

```
If iPhone
    Run current logic
Else
    Create a second view controller and push to self.navigationController
```

Comment: Push view controller cause it display full screen. I need to show it to left side of a split view controller!

Comment: Push, not present. Push into the master navigation controller